# RTP Proxy logs view

Tags: log-files, rtp

how to view rtp proxy logs separately . I actually want to view kamailio and rtp proxy logs differently.So I want to know that what are the command to view RTP proxy logs .can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use syslog engine to separete them.in syslog.conf add a local lines and number as it has examples.

RTPPROXY : instead of LOG_DEAMON  , put lOCAL(NUMBER)
rtpproxy -l 120.76.118.128 -s udp:127.0.0.1:7722 -F -m 10000 -M 20000 -d DBUG:LOG_DAEMON

KAMAILIO : in .cfg file , there is a log_facility. set this parameter as defined syslog.conf.

you can add separetly lines different files as example.

kamailio.cfg

```
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL1
xlog("LOG_LOCAL3","L_ERR","Load CALLER [$ci] FAILED");
```

rsyslog.conf

```
local1.*                                                -/var/log/kamailio/kamailio.log
local2.*                                                -/var/log/kamailio/kamailio_direction.log
local3.*                                                -/var/log/kamailio/kamailio_err.log
```

Comment: Thank you , I am at basic level so I am asking this question. I have added lOCAL3 rtpproxy -l xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -s udp:127.0.0.1:7722 -F -m 10000 -M 20000 -d DBUG:LOG_DAEMON   in startup file of rtpproxy , but exactly what command should I type in terminal to view logs of RTP proxy.

Comment: after restart rsyslog in centos , it creates a file in defined path so u can follow it. for example local3 here there is kamailio_err.log file under /var/log/kamailio  path. ("dont forget create kamailio Folder, if doesnt exist") you can follow it.

Comment: Thank you . This will help me to find out error more precisely .